# Как в SupportMapFragment (Google map) перехватывать двойной тап?

Tags: android, android-sdk, google-maps-api, google-maps

Как в SupportMapFragment (Google map) перехватывать двойной тап?

Comment: а для обычных View как это делается?

Comment: @metalurgus примеры для обычных View не подходят в моем случае, т.к. у меня SupportMapFragment

Comment: Я как раз и пытаюсь выяснить, почему они вам не подходят.

Comment: @metalurgus я уже писал не раз, что использую SupportMapFragment, а не MapView

Comment: у любого фрагмента есть свой `View`, что вам мешает проделать операции с этим `View`?

Comment: @metalurgus я в курсе. Пробовал перехватывать нажатия из View в SupportMapFragment. Не работает. В любом другом работает.